# How to mock request-promise-native for React component unit-tests?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, request-promise

Packages : Jest, Enzyme, (and Nock which did not work).

I have the following React component :

```
import ...

const request = require('request-promise-native');

class SomeSearchContainer extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ...
    };
  };

  onResponse = (response) => {
    const { var1, var2 } = response;
    if (var1) {
      this.setState(...)
    }
  };

  onSubmit = (event) => {
    const someId = this.props.someId;
    if (someId.length === 4) {
      request(
        {
          uri: `${location.href}api/${someId}`,
          json: true,
        }).then(this.onResponse)
        .catch(this.props.onResponseError);
    } else {
      this.setState(...)
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <button id="btn-search" onClick={this.onSubmit}>Search</button>
    );
  }
}

export default SomeSearchContainer;
```

I am trying to implement unit test for that, hence I would like to mock the request-promise-native and `assert` that the stage has changed accordingly based on the result (`onResponse`).

***Ideally I would like to shallow render the component, simulate a click event and assert that the state is changed (accordingly).***

I have tried various ways but either my test does not await on the request to come back, or I fail to actually mock the request.

Could you please advise ?

Answer (score 0):

Per [this example from the docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/manual-mocks.html), I **think** you probably want to do something like:

First, create a file at `__mocks__/request-promise-native.js` that will mock some sample data that would be returned by your request. That would look something like:

```js
// __mocks__/request-promise-native.js

const rpn = jest.genMockFromModule('request-promise-native');

const request = opts => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(`{
    var1: true,
    var2: "foo"
  }`);
});

rpn.request = request;

module.exports = rpn;
```

Note that the `__mocks__` folder needs to go into the root of your project, in the same directory as `node_modules`.

Then you can just write and run your tests as you would for any other React component. When the test execution gets to the part where it would normally use the `request-promise-native` library, your mocked version will automatically get swapped in and the `response` variable will get whatever JSON value you set in your mock.

Refer to the documentation above if you want slightly more complex behavior, e.g. if you want to also test the `reject()` case as well. In that case, you'd probably want to branch off of whatever got passed in the `opts` parameter to select whether to execute `resolve()` or `reject()`.

Comment: In this example of  `request-promise-native` library, maybe this isn't the best solution. Judging by its (source code)[https://github.com/request/request-promise-native/blob/master/lib/rp.js] it only exports the `request` function. So if you want to use matchers like `.toHaveBeenCalled*()` you get problems, since the type of `rpn` would be `function rpn` instead of `function`

An alternative I suggest:
```
jest.genMockFromModule('request-promise-native');
const request = jest.fn(() => {});
module.exports = request;
```

And set the mock value with `rp.mockReturnValueOnce(mockValue)`